# Pronunciation of Limacon

Tags: polar-coordinates, pronunciation

I have a presentation on common polar graphs.

one of them is the graph of $b+a\cos{\theta}$, or a limacon.

however, i'm not sure as to whether it's pronounced

-lih-muh-son

-lih-muh-con

-lie-ma-con

-lih-muh-cone

etc.. i've seen 10 pronounciation videos so far (i can't read phonics) and they all are inconsistent with one another.

does anyone know the real pronunciation??

p.s. tags are irrelevant, my apologies.

Comment: [**limaçon** /ˈlɪməsɒn/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on) (LIH-muh-son)

Comment: French word that means "snail," from Latin "limax," with reference to the shape of the snail's shell. Good pronunciation link [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lima%C3%A7on).

Comment: There is a cedilla on the c which means the c is pronounced as an s

Comment: While I love the use of the tag choice of "word-problem", I suspect that "pronunciation" might be better. :)

Comment: I DIDNT KNOW THERE WAS A PRONOUNCATION TAG IM SO STUPID HAHAHA @MarkMcClure

Comment: No wonder I didn't know, I've been spelling it wrong my entire life omg @MarkMcClure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limaçon is a French word so the c is pronounced as an s. So The first pronunciation lih-muh-son is correct